# Getting TexLive 2019 installation to work on macOS

Tags: texlive, mac, mactex, texlive-2019

I am not an expert on Unix based systems.

I installed [TexLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) 2019 on my mac (Mojave 10.14.6) and in the end it advises me to:

> Add /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/man to MANPATH.
>
> Add /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/info to INFOPATH.
>
> Most importantly, add /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin
> to your PATH for current and future sessions.

The 2018 version had a graphical interface which was easier to handle.

**Does anyone know what exactly should I do?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If you use the [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) installer, all of this is done for you.

Comment: The thing is that full MacTeX is huge. I actually installed the lighter version through this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470265/best-as-of-2019-way-to-install-latex/470285#470285). I do recommend it for anyone. I followed the steps there and I got it working fine. Also it only stores approximately 500MB. I will leave the question here for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following [this guide](https://www.pegaxchange.com/2017/06/17/mac-os-x-path-variable/), I think I've managed to solve the issue. I work with 10.11.6 El Capitan. Let me resume: first and most important, I've added the third string to the PATH variable by typing in a terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

then added the string `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy` as last line

[image: terminal screenshot]

press CTRL + X to close and press Y to save changes. If you close and re-open the terminal window and type `echo $PATH` you should see the new path added to the environment variable.

Similarly for the other two. Always in the terminal type

```
sudo nano /etc/manpaths
```

add the `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/man` string, exit and save.
For the last one I have some doubts on the effectiveness, since my file was initially void. Anyway, as usual, type in the terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/infopaths
```

and add `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/info`

Finally, check that Tex Live Utility is reading the correct path (2019). Open that app, go to the preferences and point to the path of the 2019 version `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy`

[image: Tex Live Utility preferences panel]

Now Tex Live Utility should update the packages.

Comment: I think this is related to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273893/190479) on Linux, right?

Comment: I don't know, because I just followed the instructions on the linked article and applied them to our case. Did you try my solution?