# pdflatex does not compile on fresh Texlive 2021 install

Tags: pdftex

I installed Texlive2021 fresh after deleting previous installations of texlive packages. The installation fine but the following file:

LaTeX test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}
```

gave the following output:

```
$ pdflatex test2.tex 

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex) entering extended mode

(./test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>

! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: X
```

The previous installation of texlive worked fine. I could not make any out of this and would be thankful for your kind help and suggestions.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?  I don't suppose the command `kpsewhich article.cls` shows anything?

Answer (score 0):

A reboot of the system after adding the value of TEXMFROOT via *tlmgr conf texmf* worked and now the system just started to work...

However, please could you let me know: why was the reboot required? Changing the values in .bashrc and then invoking *source .bashrc* was done and I believe the *texhash* changes take immediate effect.

With my regards and all the very best wishes...

partha

Comment: if you just edited bashrc and profile without executing them or starting a new shell they would not have taken effect although odd that you found a texlive 2021 on your path.

Comment: does not `source .bashrc` execute the changes in *.bashrc*?

Comment: yes sorry disdn't see that comment. Yes, it does, so long as you start tex from that shell (not eg from an editor started from the desktop)

Comment: yes, I did start from a terminal shell.... this made me surprised: what extra configurations were set after the reboot, and that is where the present query lies...

Comment: you should only have to set the PATH and not set TEXINPUTS so what you describe should not happen and as we can't reproduce it I'd just pretend it never happened and move on...

Comment: you dodn't say how you installed texlive, whether it was the system texlive installed via apt (or other linux package manager) or the upstreal texlive from tug ?

Comment: I installed texlive via the CTAN mirror, using `install-tl.zip` download. Yes, thanks for your suggestion: to move on, since this cannot be reproduced...; but thanks for your time and help....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132795/discussion-between-partha-pratim-ghosh-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error that was caused by the MacTex installer configuring itself with admin ownership.

That issue can be bypassed by running pdflatex with admin privileges:

```
sudo pdflatex test2.tex
```

A better solution, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3744/how-do-i-set-up-mactex-so-admin-rights-arent-necessary), is to change the ownership of the installation:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:mygroup /usr/local/texlive
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score -1):

I saw the same error, but running

```bash
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

fixed the problem without a reboot. I had installed LaTeX with `sudo apt install texlive` initially. (This was on Ubuntu 20.04.3.)